# App for listening to kids reading text and making corrections (in real time)

Tags: voice, voice-recognition

How hard would it be to design an app that displays text to be read, by a child.

The app listens to the child, and, makes corrections, to what they say, ad they read.

Where can I find such an app?

Would anyone be willing to design one?

I think, if it could work properly, it would be very useful.

It would have to listen to voice, and, not only, understand, and decipher, what was being said, (and go out quickly), but also make corrections to voice, tone, and pronunciation, in real time.

How could this be done?

Would anyone be willing to implement such a system?

I am looking forward to any software that does this.

(I wanted to add a voice correction tag below, but couldn't find any).

Thanks.